# Distinguish quotes ' and apostrophes while tokenizing with regex

Tags: python, regex

Having some text, i want to tokenize it on words properly. In the text may appear:

- words with apostrophe in middle (Can't, I'll,the accountant‘s books )
- words with apostrophe in the end (the employers‘ association , I spent most o’ the day replacin’ the broken bit)
- quotes, staying directly after the word or between words like : word'word
- text is splitted on sentences, but the can be many sentences inside a quote, also, the  word with apostroph can stay inside a quote
- different symbols for qutes like either ' ' both for opening and closing or one is ' other is ` or ´, etc...

What yould be your suggestion to solve it?
Is it solvable with regex ( Python re for example?
I want words with apostrophe do not split  and quotes to split from word tokens

Parcing commont text, The Fellowship Of The Ring.txt for example is tricky a little bit:

- input : had hardly any 'government'.
  output: ["had","hardly","any","'","government","'"] (recognized as quote)
- A rather larger body, varying at need, was employed to 'beat the bounds'
  is a quote, however is tricky because of ending s'
- 'It isn't natural, and trouble will come of it!' apostrophe inside a quote
- 'Elves and Dragons'_ I says to him. is a quote, howewer, s' again.

Comment: What have you tried so far and please add example of input and desired output?

Comment: are you restricted to using regular expressions? If not, have a look at any natural language processing toolkit, such as http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: not only regex actualy i have own fast string tokenizer but i just wonder how to determine that in some cases like with dragons' :D

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try to break down your cases. If you want to split by words (meaning that a word has spaces on both ends) probably a simple `split` would do its job.

```
>>> my_str = "words like that'"
>>> my_str.split(' ')
['words', 'like', "that'"]
>>>
```

If it's more complicated, regex seems to be a better idea. You can use `(a|b)`, meaning *match a or b*. My suggestion would be to experiment more, the perfect place to experiment is here: [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). To make things clearer select 'Python' in the left panel!